# Drawing a specfic set of figures with AngularJS and Javascript and saving them with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm experimenting with AngularJS and Javascript and MongoDB.

I want to be able to draw a specific figure on the screen, that looks like this:

[image: figure needed]

I have done the above in pure JS and HMTL which is bad if I want to save everything on a database... So I'm trying to do it in AngularJS and using JSON which hopefully might help me saving stuff into the database.

The code I have so far is just experimental:

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('triangular', []);


app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.graph = {'width': 1000, 'height': 1000};

    $scope.circles = [

        JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 20, \"r\":15}"),

        {"x": 50, "y": 60, "r":20},

        {"x": 180, "y": 100, "r":40}
    ];

    $scope.circles.push(JSON.parse("{\"x\": 85, \"y\": 120, \"r\":10}"));

    $scope.rectangles = [
    /*
        {'x':220,  'y':220,  'width' : 300, 'height' : 100},
        {'x':520,  'y':220,  'width' : 300, 'height' : 100}
        */
    ];

}
);


function toggle_visibility(id)
{
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if ( e.style.display == 'block' )
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<html ng-app="triangular">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


</head>

<label>Num questões:</label>
<input Id="nrects" class="span3" style="margin: 0pt auto;" type="text" placeholder="Num questões..." data-provide="typeahead" data-items="1"/>

<div class="span3"></div>
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Draw" onClick="toggle_visibility('scenes')"/></div>


<div id="scenes" style="display: none;">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <svg ng-attr-height="{{graph.height}}" ng-attr-width="{{graph.width}}">

    <circle ng-repeat="circle in circles"

            ng-attr-cx="{{circle.x}}"

            ng-attr-cy="{{circle.y}}"

            ng-attr-r="{{circle.r}}">
    </circle>

     <rect ng-repeat="rect in rectangles"

           ng-attr-x="{{rect.x}}"

           ng-attr-y="{{rect.y}}"

           ng-attr-width="{{rect.width}}"

           ng-attr-height="{{rect.height}}">

     </rect>

     </svg>
 </div>
    </div>
```

My question now is, how can I define functions inside the JS that can help me with the code modularity and drawing?

I want to be able to have for example two vectors one with the X coordinates and the other with the Y coordinates of the rectangles and then iterate trough that vectors while pushing the JSON objects to $scope.rectangles such that image appeared in my browser with all the components in JSON... This would help me a lot with the writing the objects for the Database I think...